# Retrieving the Object of a Python List Instead of the Address

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm attempting to retrieve info listed in a drop-down box on a webpage.  The objects represent different configurations.  I'd like to store the contents of the list & then do a search to see if the file I want is listed there.  Here's what the code for that section of the web page looks like:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/Files/Upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="page-header">
    <!-- <h1>User files</h1> -->
    <div class="form-inline pull-right" style="line-height:36px">
        <span class="help-inline">Active config:</span>
        <select id="active_config">
            <option>
                None
            </option>
            <option>
                Example.ncd
            </option>
            <option>
                Classroom.ncd
            </option>
            <option>
                Sting.ncd
            </option>
            <option>
                MyTestConfig.ncd
            </option>
            <option selected="selected">
                Vacation.ncd
            </option>
            <option>
                Recital.ncd
            </option>
        </select>
```

So, I counted the objects listed in the drop-down box...

```
NumberOfConfigFiles = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option"))
```

Then I stored the list in a variable...

```
configList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option")
```

Here's the issue I'm having.  When I attempt to retrieve items in the configList using... `configList[0]`, `configList[2]`, `configList`, etc.. it appears to return information regarding the object instead of returning the object.

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x02D9EC50>, <seleni
um.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x02DB23B0>, <selenium.webdr
iver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x02DB23F0>, <selenium.webdriver.rem
ote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x02DB2710>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webe
lement.WebElement object at 0x02DB20F0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.W
ebElement object at 0x02DB2390>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElemen
t object at 0x02DB2410>]
```

Assuming this list contains the objects I desire & I did store them correctly, how to I get it to retrieve the object rather than the address?

Comment: You are getting the objects, it's just that the string representation shows the address.  You have a list of `WebElement` objects and can use the API on them as usual.

Comment: Are you saying to continue with the assumption that my objects are there & to continue with checking if the file I'm looking for is in the list?

Comment: Your mistake seems to be thinking you should have the strings inside the `<option>` tags when your XPath selects the `<option>` tags themselves (as `WebElement` objects).  As suggested below, you can use e.g. `configList[0].text` to get the contained string.

Comment: You were correct, @Jake Cobb, that was indeed what I needed.  Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list and  call whatever methods like `.text` etc..  that are relevant to get what you want from each object stored in the list.

Comment: When I add 'extract()' to the command, I receive this error:

E     AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'extract'
AttributeError

Comment: sorry my mistake, was not paying attention, you can just iterate over the list and call whatever methods you want on each object

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying operate as if the 'list' has the objects.  With that in mind, I did a quick test with what I expect to be in "configList[2]".  When I do a... `assert configList[2] == "Classroom.ncd"`, I receive this error:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'.  I'm trying to make sense of this...

Comment: if you iterate over the list and `print ele.tag_name` what do you see? where ele each is element in the loop

Comment: Adding '.text' to the end of 'configList' seems to retrieve what I need.  I thought I'd tried that previously, but I clearly was doing something wrong & didn't quite understand the error it was giving me.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted.